# Can't take mysqldump of long argument list

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I've tried using previously accepted solutions for my problem, but they aren't working:

Example "id_list"

```
[jlefler@server ~]$ cat id_list | tail -10
17900018
17900019
17900020
17900021
17900022
17900023
17900024
17900025
17900026
17900027[jlefler@server ~]$ cat id_list |wc -l
51624
```

Command I'm trying to execute to dump 2000 id's at a time:

```
xargs -a id_list -d '\n' -n 2000 sh -c 'mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where="id in ($0 $@)" >> dump.sql' x
```

However I get this unexpected output:

```
[jlefler@server ~]$ xargs -a id_list -d '\n' -n 2000 sh -c 'mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where="id in ($0 $@)" >> dump.sql' x
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17851966
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17853966
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17855967
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17857967
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17859975
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17861978
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17863978
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17865978
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17867978
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17869978
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17871978
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17873979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17875979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17877979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17879979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17881979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17883979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17885979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17887979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17889979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17891979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17893979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17895979
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17897980
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17899986
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
"ysqldump: Couldn't find table: "17850378
```

Basically, the end result should be something like this:

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where="id in (17900018,17900019,17900020...)" >> dump.sql
```

It takes 2000 IDs at a time adds them to dump.sql and then goes to the next 2000 until all the IDs are read from the file.

With echo command to display output, I get the following:

```
)17853963ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17851964
)17855964ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17853964
)17857964ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17855965
)17859972ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17857965
)17861975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17859973
)17863975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17861976
)17865975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17863976
)17867975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17865976
)17869975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17867976
)17871975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17869976
)17873976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17871976
)17875976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17873977
)17877976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17875977
)17879976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17877977
)17881976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17879977
)17883976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17881977
)17885976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17883977
)17887976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17885977
)17889976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17887977
)17891976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17889977
)17893976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17891977
)17895976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17893977
)17897977ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17895977
)17899983ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17897978
)17850375ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17899984
 17900027)mp -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (17850376
)17853963ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17851964
)17855964ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17853964
)17857964ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17855965
)17859972ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17857965
)17861975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17859973
)17863975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17861976
)17865975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17863976
)17867975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17865976
)17869975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17867976
)17871975ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17869976
)17873976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17871976
)17875976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17873977
)17877976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17875977
)17879976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17877977
)17881976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17879977
)17883976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17881977
)17885976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17883977
)17887976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17885977
)17889976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17887977
)17891976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17889977
)17893976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17891977
)17895976ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17893977
)17897977ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17895977
)17899983ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17897978
)17850375ump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17899984
 17900027)mp -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (x 17850376
```

Comment: What do you want to do with each batch of 2000 rows? What do you want to happen after each batch of 2000 rows is generated?

The question needs some clarification.

Comment: I've added additional comments/clarification in my original post.

Comment: looks like you may be dealing with dos/windows line endings {`\r\n`); try running `head -3 id_list | od -c` and if you see `\r` in the output this would confirm my hunch; a quick filx would be `dos2unix id_list` (only need to run once to remove the `\r` characters from the file)

Comment: yeah, if I add dos/windows line endings to my `id_list` file I can generate the same output as what you're seeing; so definitely need to get rid of the `\r` characters

Answer (score 0):

**NOTES:**

- OP's current syntax issue appears to be due to dos/windows line endings (`\r\n`) in the input file (`id_list`)
- assuming OP can remove the `\r` characters the next issue will likely be an invalid `in()` list ... which is what this answer will focus on ...

Sample input file:

```
$ cat id_list
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Modified `xargs` call:

```
$ xargs -a id_list -n 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

Adding `echo` to see what the current code is generating:

```
$ xargs -a id_list -n 3 bash -c 'echo mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where="id in ($0 $@)"'
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (1 2 3)
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (4 5 6)
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (7 8 9)
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id in (10 )
```

**NOTES:**

- OP has tagged the question with `bash` so I've replaced `sh -c` with `bash -c`
- from this output it appears we need to replace spaces with commas for the `--where/in()` clause
- it also appears we need to add a pair of escaped double quotes in order for them to show up around the `--where/in()` clause

One idea for addressing these issues:

```
$ xargs -a id_list -n 3 bash -c 'list=$(sed "s/ /,/g;s/,$//g" <<< "$0 $@"); echo mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where="\"id in ($list)\""'
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where=id mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where="id in (1,2,3)"
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where="id in (4,5,6)"
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where="id in (7,8,9)"
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where="id in (10)"
```

Comment: How do I redirect the output to an actual file? This doesn't work:

xargs -a id_list -n 500 bash -c 'list=$(sed "s/ /,/g;s/,$//g" <<< "$0 $@"); echo mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table --where="\"id in ($list)\"" >> dump.sql' > source

Comment: define *`doesn't work`* ... syntax error? runtime error? something else? did you remove the `echo`?

Comment: Each mysqldump statement has to concatenate the results to dump.sql but I run the command above it puts the statements into the file dump.sql rather than executing the statements. And yes, I removed the 'echo' and I tried the >> dump.sql before and after the final quote character.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different way of approaching to this problem (without `xargs`).
I tried to re-create your scenario and it is working for me.
Have a look below.

**Generating Sample file for Ids:**

```
for i in {1000..15000};do echo "${i}" >> /tmp/ids.txt;done
```

**The Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the total count of Ids present in the file.
filecount=`wc -l /tmp/ids.txt | awk '{print $1}'`

while [ "${filecount}" != "0" ]
do
    # Get the first 2000 ids from the file and make them comma-separated.
    ids=`head -2000 /tmp/ids.txt | sed -ze 's/\n/,/g' -e 's/,$//g'`
    # Take the dump
    mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info db table_name --where="id in (${ids})" >> /tmp/dump.sql
    # Remove the 2000 ids so that we can proceed to the next ids 
    sed -i '1,2000d' /tmp/ids.txt

    # Necessary to end the while loop :)
    filecount=`wc -l /tmp/ids.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo "${filecount}"
done
```

**The Output:**

```
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
12001
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
10001
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
8001
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
6001
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
4001
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
2001
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
1
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
0
```

I was able to successfully take the dump with this. The numbers in the output are nothing but `echo "${filecount}"` from the above script.

**Note:**
I would recommend to make a copy of your `id_list` file before proceeding with this approach, since we are removing ids from the file for which backup is taken. (For me it was just a sample self-generated file)