# How to redirect the mysqldump to output file using xargs?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have same problem as mentioned in this below query.

[Can't take mysqldump of long argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74648579/cant-take-mysqldump-of-long-argument-list/74649701#74649701)

Any idea how to redirect the mysqldump result to a output file?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the result of xargs with `>` just like any other shell command.

For example if I have an xargs pipeline that runs three commands:

```
% echo "1\n2\n3" | xargs -n 1 "echo"
1
2
3
```

I can just use `>` to redirect the output of all three commands:

```
% echo "1\n2\n3" | xargs -n 1 "echo" > output

% more output
1
2
3
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to concatenate mysqldump and append in same file using below command xargs -a empids.txt -n 200 bash -c 'list=$(sed "s/ /,/g;s/,$//g" <<< "$0 $@"); mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --compact --no-create-info org employee --where="\"emp_id in ($list)\"" >> dump.sql'

Comment: My example is just meant to demonstrate how to redirect the output of xargs. I understand you are running mysqldump commands, not echo commands. It's up to you to read my answer and adapt it to the command you need.

Comment: @AbiramiRamkumar I have added one probable solution to this on the thread you mentioned since that thread is 2 months old. Have a look and let me know if it helps. [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74648579/cant-take-mysqldump-of-long-argument-list/75483684#75483684)